# How to do parameter replacement within single quote for @@ postgres operator

Tags: postgresql, jdbc

I am having issues with combining couple of different things together. I have tried a lot of things suggested on SO but nothing worked, hence posting my question.

So the requirements are

1. I need to build the dynamic query (to search jsonb column type) in Java
2. I need to use prepared statements of Java (to avoid sql injection)
3. I need to replace parameter which is inside single quotes

This query in CLI works perfectly

```
select * from items where cnt @@ '$.**.text like_regex "#finance" flag "i"';
```

The bit that I want to parameterise is "#finance". So when I build this query

```
select * from items where cnt @@ '$.**.text like_regex ? flag "i"';
```

When executing I get following error

```
"The column index is out of range: 1, number of columns: 0."
```

It's because ? is within single quote so jdbc driver is not able to identify as replaceable parameter perhaps.

The closest question/discussion I could find is in this post: [JDBC Prepared statement parameter inside json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37422886/jdbc-prepared-statement-parameter-inside-json).

I have tried it however this does not work for me for some reason. They query now I run is

```
select * from items where cnt @@ ?::jsonb
```

but with this I get following error

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: jsonb @@ jsonb
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 106
```

I have tried various other ways like escaping single quotes etc but nothing really worked. I have very limited knowledge of PostgreSQL, so any help would be appreciated.

Postgres version: 13.1
Java version: 15

Answer (score 2):

> select * from items where cnt @@ ?::jsonb

The thing on the right of the @@ needs to be a jsonpath, not jsonb.  So casting it to jsonb is clearly wrong.  Try casting it to jsonpath instead.

Comment: Brilliant that worked. Sorry seems like this was pretty dumb stuff I was doing :). I should up skill myself in postgres. Saved my day.